# JQuery Masonry better optimize whitespaces by changing the order of items

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am currently working with the following code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rn0ms6q6/2/)

As you can see I have some items that occupy 50% ("item") of the horizontal space and 1 item that occupies 100% ("item double"). The height of the items may vary but not significantly.

```
.item { width: 50%; }
.item.double { width: 100%; }


$(window).load( function() {

    $container = $('#container');
    $container.masonry({
        "itemSelector": ".item",
        "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
        "transitionDuration": 0
    });

});
```

Unfortunately, depending on the order of the items and the two column layout (which is one of my media query cases), white space may be huge and occupy half of the available space.

Is there anyway to fix this using JQuery Masonry or do I have to resort to Isotope (or custom code)? The fix would make only the necessary rearrangements, keeping the original order as much as possible.

I have studied the Masonry options and the related Stackoverflow questions, but I have not yet stumbled upon a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masonry could actually be extended to rearrange the sequence of items, but I finally opted for the [Isotope packery layout](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html). The media queries trigger just fine, with which I had troubles using the Masonry script. It looks like I still need to mix-in some "filler" items into the .isotope element to avoid white spaces that pop up right in the middle column. If anyone ever comes across this issue, it's worth choosing Isotope over the Masonry package, there are lot more options, even if it comes with a commercial license.